# error C2512: 'LayerTwoTree' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I have two header files like this:

```
#ifndef LAYER_ONE_TREE_H
#define LAYER_ONE_TREE_H

#include "Utils.h"
#include "LayerTwoTree.h"

class LayerOneTreeNode{
public:
    friend class LayerOneTree;
    friend class LayerTwoTree;

    .
    .
    .
    LayerTwoTree* S_U1;// A pointer to the root of a layerTwoTree

    LayerOneTreeNode(){
        S_U1 = new LayerTwoTree; //here is the error Error  1   erro C2512: 'LayerTwoTree' : no appropriate default constructor available
        S_U1->init();
    }
};

class LayerOneTree{
public:
    LayerOneTree(){
    }
    .
    .
    .

private:
    .
    .
    .
};
#endif
```

and the second header:

```
#ifndef LAYER_TWO_TREE_H
#define LAYER_TWO_TREE_H

#include "Utils.h"
#include "LayerOneTree.h"


class LayerTwoTreeNode{
public:
    friend class LayerTwoTree;
    friend class LayerOneTree;

    .
    .
    .

    //constructor
    LayerTwoTreeNode(Point v = Point(), LayerTwoTreeNode *l = nullptr,
        LayerTwoTreeNode *r = nullptr, NodeColor c = Black)
        : key(v), color(c), left(l), right(r)
    {}
};

class LayerTwoTree{
public:
    friend class LayerOneTree;
    friend class LayerOneTreeNode;
    .
    .
    .
    LayerTwoTree(){
    }

    LayerOneTreeNode*     fatherNode;     //the father node of this tree

};

#endif
```

I dont know why Im getting "no appropriate default constructor available Error" when Im trying to have a `LayerTwoTree`in my `LayerOneTree`. I think the problem is because I want to have a `LayerTwoTree` in `LayerOneTree` and also a `LayerOneTree` in my `LayerTwoTree`. Is there any way to fix this problem? please comment if you need to know more details about the code.

Comment: There is no default constructor available because the class is at that point not fully defined. Remove the functions from the class body into a separate implementation file that is compiled with both class definitions in view.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , The implementation of these two headers are in separate cpp files. What do you mean by "Remove the functions from the class body into a separate implementation file that is `compiled with both class definitions`"? can you show me an example? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis:

Assume some file includes LayerTwoTree.h, the relevant lines are:

```
#ifndef LAYER_TWO_TREE_H
#define LAYER_TWO_TREE_H
#include "LayerOneTree.h"
```

At this point, the content of LayerOneTree.h are included in the translation unit:

```
#ifndef LAYER_ONE_TREE_H
#define LAYER_ONE_TREE_H
#include "LayerTwoTree.h"
```

At this point, the content of LayerTwoTree.h are included in the translation unit again:

```
#ifndef LAYER_TWO_TREE_H
#endif
```

Note that all the things in between the include guards have been skipped, because the macro was already defined! So, back to LayerOneTree.h:

```
class LayerOneTreeNode{
public:
    friend class LayerOneTree;
    friend class LayerTwoTree;
```

At this point, the two tree classes are declare, but incomplete.

```
    LayerTwoTree* S_U1;// A pointer to the root of a layerTwoTree
```

Creating pointers to incomplete types is okay, so this works...

```
    LayerOneTreeNode(){
        S_U1 = new LayerTwoTree; //here is the error Error  1   erro C2512: 'LayerTwoTree' : no appropriate default constructor available
        S_U1->init();
    }
```

...but at this point you are trying to create an instance of this incomplete class, about which MSC complains with a slightly misleading error message.

### Solution:

Use this schema:

```
// declare classes
class Foo;
class Bar;
// define classes
class Foo {
    Bar* p;
public:
    // declare ctor
    Foo();
};
class Bar {
    Foo* p;
public:
    // declare ctor
    Bar();
};
// define ctor
Foo::Foo() {
    p = new Bar();
}
Bar::Bar() {
    p = new Foo();
}
```

Alternatively, search for "circular dependency C++" and you will find many more explanations.